# Count maximum value in each group with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` looking like

```
    school   score   student_id
0    1        100.0   965
1    2        64.0    1483
2    2        100.0   1055
3    2        68.0    1806
4    1        100.0    971
```

I want to find how many maximum scores in each group and get something like this:

```
school count_max
  1       2
  2       1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please do add your tried command in your question as your efforts, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: What is `count_max`? The number of rows per group where `score` is equal to the max in the group? Or the maximum overall?

Comment: I think `count_max` is the number of rows per group where score is equal to the max in the group

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `count_max` means that the `score` column equals `100`, you can do:

```
df.loc[df.score==100, 'max_score'] = True
df.max_score.fillna(False, inplace=True)
df.groupby('school')['max_score'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. For the case `maximum score` means the overall maximum of data in column `score`

You can get the maximum score with [`.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) and then compare the `score` equal to this max. Then, group by `school` by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get the count of entries matching the max by [`GroupBy.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), as follows:

```
(df['score'].eq(df['score'].max())
            .groupby(df['school'])
            .sum()
).reset_index(name='count_max')
```

**Input**

(**Added one more row for extra test case of zero match case:**)

```
print(df)

   school  score  student_id
0       1  100.0         965
1       2   64.0        1483
2       2  100.0        1055
3       2   68.0        1806
4       1  100.0         971
5       3   99.0        2096              <==   Added a row here
```

**Result:**

```
   school  count_max
0       1          2
1       2          1
2       3          0
```

#### 2. For the case `maximum score` means the maximum of `score` within a group of the same `school`:

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html), [`Series.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), [`.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) as follows:

```
(df.groupby('school')['score']
   .agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().loc[x.max()])
   .reset_index(name='count_max')
)
```

**Explanation:**

Here the code `x.value_counts().loc[x.max()])` take x (passed by `.agg()` to the lambda function) as the portion of pandas Series of column `score` under each group of `school`.  The code call `value_counts()` to get the counts of all unique values. Its return type is a pandas Series which we can use `.loc[]` to locate the entry of `x.max()` which is the maximum value within the group.  The return value will be the count of entries of the maximum value within that group.

**Output:**

(Based on the input added one more row above:)

```
   school  count_max
0       1          2
1       2          1
2       3          1
```